# Javascript displaying sequence of events

Tags: javascript, concurrency, dom-events

I have a grid 4x4 and I'd like to show sequence of colours such that a different colour shows in a single cell one at a time.

Using loop doesn't work:

```
   var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
     for(var i=0; i<sequence.length; i=i+3) {
        setTimeout(function(){ table.rows[sequence[i]].cells[sequence[i+1]].className = sequence[i+2]; }, timeout);
        setTimeout(function(){ table.rows[sequence[i]].cells[sequence[i+1]].className = 'black'; }, timeout+1999);
          timeout = timeout+2000;
     }
  } catch(err) { alert(err); }   
}
```

Using statements sequentially does:

```
  setTimeout(function(){ table.rows[sequence[0]].cells[sequence[1]].className = 'black'; }, 2999);
  setTimeout(function(){ table.rows[sequence[3]].cells[sequence[4]].className = sequence[5]; }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function(){ table.rows[sequence[3]].cells[sequence[4]].className = 'black'; }, 4999);
```

(...)

Does anyone know why loop doesn't work? I tried clearing timeout but no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical closure problem : i has the value of the end of the loop when the functions are called.

I like to use objects to encapsulate vars and avoid those problems.
For example :

```
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
function C(i, timeout) {
    this.i=i;
    this.timeout = timeout;
}
C.prototype.doThing = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ table.rows[sequence[obj.i]].cells[sequence[obj.i+1]].className = sequence[i+2]; }, timeout);
    setTimeout(function(){ table.rows[sequence[obj.i]].cells[sequence[obj.i+1]].className = 'black'; }, timeout+1999);
};

 for(var i=0; i<sequence.length; i=i+3) {
        new C(i, timeout)).doThing();
        timeout = timeout+2000;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Silly question but do you know of any source for list of common issues / such classical problems? I realise that such knowledge comes with practice but some reference would be of great help.

Comment: I recommend you [this tutorial](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) : you'll learn most what you have to learn about javascript.

Comment: Really, do it. You'll have the head hurting a little at beginning but you'll end much better in javascript and a good understanding of closures and functions will help you in other modern languages too.

Answer (score 2):

Use self invoking function like this to pass different value of `i` otherwise you are passing same value of it:

```
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');

 for(var i=0; i<sequence.length; i=i+3) {
   (function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){ table.rows[sequence[i]].cells[sequence[i+1]].className = sequence[i+2]; }, timeout);
    setTimeout(function(){ table.rows[sequence[i]].cells[sequence[i+1]].className = 'black'; }, timeout+1999);
      timeout = timeout+2000;
   })(i)

} catch(err) { alert(err); }
```